# Remember "I hate hats" setting between years

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

Instead of forcing me to opt out of hats every year, can you please make Stack Exchange remember my setting between years?

Comment: I don't think it takes that much effort to opt-out once a year. Who knows, maybe you would want to take part next time?

Comment: @Ambo100 I took part when it started over on Gaming (now known as Arqade) where it actually made sense.  In fact, I placed in the top 3 there the first year it ran.  Now, I just find it to be unfunny and a waste of time/effort for everyone involved.

Comment: And the *Haters Gonna Hate*...

Comment: Be a hatter, not a hater!

Comment: @Powerlord nobody is forcing you to do anything. Just ignore the snow flake, same way people ignore ads for example.

Answer (score 4):

I made a scientific wild ass guess here but I suspected being able to see and not see hats is cached in html 5 localstorage.  It seems Stack Exchange keeps track during Winter Bash, but not after that (as per balpha's comment).

The web dev console (which I have no business being in shows the HTML5 bits).

[image]

Looks like the settings/keys are unique to this year

I'm not sure if they've always done this or if its just this year. In theory though they *could* store it forever, assuming its the same key but its probably simpler not to assume that people are OK with the 2-3 clicks a year to disable it.

Comment: No, the localStorage stuff is just a a cache. If we hadn't stored it on our side, you'd have to opt out on every single Stack Exchange site individually. Also, opting out doesn't only stop *you* from seeing other people's hats, it also stops *them* from seeing *yours* (be it on your profile or on [the WB site itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Nun.png). So we have the data during Winter Bash, we just don't store it accross years.

Comment: edited to reflect that , well as well as I understood it anyway ;p